# how can I capitalize the first word and the last word in a string in C program?

Tags: c, string

I'm coding a c program about string. I have trouble when I want to capitalize on the first word and the last word in a string. Anyone can help me, please. Thank so much. Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h> 
void fun(int tc, char []);
int main() {
        int tc;
        char string[100];
        printf("Enter tc: ");
        scanf("%d", &tc);
        fflush(stdin);
        printf("Enter a string:\n");
        gets(string);
        printf("\nThe original string: \n%s", string);
        fun(tc, string);
        printf("\n\nThe string after processing: \n%s", string);
        printf("\n\nOutput: \n%s", string);
        return 0;
} 
void fun(int tc ,char s[]) {
        int c = 0;
        int spaceCounter = 0; //First word not to be capitalized
        while (s[c] != '\0')
        {
                if(tc == 1){
                        if ((spaceCounter  == 0) && s[c] >= 'a' && s[c] <= 'z')
                        {
                                s[c] = s[c] - 32; // You can use toupper function for the same.
                        }
                        else if(s[c] == ' ')
                        {
                                spaceCounter++; //Reached the next word
                        }
                        c++;
                }
        }
}
```

Comment: Who or what text suggested using `gets()` and `fflush(stdin)`?

Comment: "to capitalize .... the last word in a string" requires code to save a word and then, if not the last, capitalize it. - then print it.  So start by saving a "word".

Comment: Never use `gets`, google it to learn why.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say your string is `s`. You can start capitalizing from beginning until you reach a space, meaning the first word is over. Then you can find the end of string and start processing it backwards until you find a space, meaning the last word is over.

```
void capitalize(char *s) 
{
    // capitalize first word
    while (!isspace(*s))
    {
        *s = toupper(*s);
        s++;
    }

    // reach end of s
    while(*s++);

    // capitalize last word
    s--;
    while (!isspace(*s))
    {
        *s = toupper(*s);
        s--;
    }
}
```

**edit:** the code would work if the string has at least two words. Add a check for null terminator in every loop to make it safe.

Comment: Consider what the 2nd `while (!isspace(*s))` does on unexpected lines like `capitalize(" ") `.